# Remove Mysql row after specified time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a computer reservation system, where user chooses a computer and select the time how long he will be using this PC. In that time other persons can't reserve this pc, I need to find a solution, how to automaticaly delete all rows containing reserved pc's after their time expires. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an untested answer, that may only be a suggestion, but I just started looking at these, so am interested in feedback as well.  i'm still working through possibilities and drawbacks, but it might well suit your need.

Take a look at MySQL Events, an article about it is [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/), and official syntax at [Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).
Per the article:

> An event is similar to a trigger. However, rather than running in
>   response to a data change, events can be scheduled to run any number
>   of times during a specific period. In effect, it’s a database-only
>   cron job.

Pondering this, I'd envision a procedure that deleted anything >1hr (if that's the expiration).  This procedure would be TRIGGERED on new inserts to get rid of anything expired at that moment, but **also** in an event to run every 15 minutes or so so that automatic deletes by the trigger aren't dependant on somebody else adding a reservation to trigger that procedure.

Comment: If you want to actually delete the rows, using an event that calls a procedure containing your `delete from ... where ...` should work really well. Just schedule the event to go off often enough.  On the other hand, if you use a start and end time like some of the other answers, you keep records of all the reservations.  Depends on what you need.

Answer (score 5):

The common way to handle this is to store an `expires_at` timestamp on the `reservation` row. Then your query to find any "open" reservations would have `WHERE 'expires_at' < NOW()` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

If your server is linux, you can use **cron jobs** to check once a day every reservation dates. If these dates have expired .. modified field reserves to be available.

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would do it this way:

- when storing a reservation, store `date_from` and `date_to` both of datatype `DATETIME`
- when checking if there is a computer free check for all computers and filter with `WHERE '{$my_date}' >= date_to AND '{$my_date}' <= date_from` - by this You should be able to get all the PCs that are not reserved within a certain time...

Comment: I wrote the reservation system for our hotel, and this is how I do it too, only using dates instead of `DATETIME` since we don't sell rooms by the hour.

Answer (score 1):

To be complete in the solution, you need to run a CRON job which calls a query to remove all reservations that have a reservation_time + (15 * 60) < unix_timestamp().

I am assuming you have a time that the reservation was placed or started and are using UNIX/Epoch Timestamps.

Instead of doing a expires_now, if you know it will always be a fixed interval ie 15 minutes, you can do:

```
DELETE FROM reservations WHERE  reservation_time + (15 * 60) < unix_timestamp()
```

Something you could look into is managing cron job's from PHP, http://www.highonphp.com/cron-job-manager.

The above script will, when a reservation is created, insert an entry into /etc/cron.d/ and you could configure it to run at the expected reservation endtime. Then inside the php file which would be executed, you could do:

```
DELETE FROM reservations WHERE id = :id
```