# MySQL give rows a lifetime

Tags: mysql

How can I create a lifetime of a row so after a specific time say 2 weeks the row will automatically erase? Any info would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038675/remove-mysql-row-after-specified-time this might help you

Answer (score 5):

RDBMS don't generally allow rows to automatically self destruct. It's bad for business.

More seriously, some ideas, depending on your exact needs

- run a scheduled job to run a `DELETE` to remove rows based on some date/time column
- (more complex idea) use a partitioned table with a sliding window to move older rows to another partition
- use a view to only show rows less than 2 weeks old

Answer (score 2):

Add a `timestamp` column to the table that defaults to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and install a cron job on the server that frequently runs and prunes old records.

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE datediff(now(), myTimestamp) >= 14;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add timestamp column and always select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE timetampColumn>=date_sub(now(), interval 2 week);
```

It is better if you don't need to erase the data and you want to show only data from last 2 weeks.