# Does mysql can give each row a specified lifetime to be deleted automatically?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'd like to know if mysql(or mariadb) offers a function for the expiration that a row can be removed automatically in the DB without using any extra scheduler program nor using any SQL like `DELETE`.

This should happen or define when you create a table so that once `INSERT` occurs it starts to manage it.

There are many related questions here:

[MySQL how to make value expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220334/mysql-how-to-make-value-expire)

[Remove Mysql row after specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038675/remove-mysql-row-after-specified-time)

[MySQL give rows a lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522137/mysql-give-rows-a-lifetime)

However, I couldn't find the answer. I am not curious about using `WHERE` nor `DELETE`.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I think the closest thing to what you are looking for is creating an **Event** to remove old rows, just like someone explained in one of the links you posted.

Comment: @EnricoDias I don't want `the closest thing`. What I am looking for is `the thing`.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Short answer- No

Comment: @Strawberry It can be used in some cases. For example, 'verification code'. Sometimes, we just need data for a single time and we don't need its log. And it should be removed in a certain time.

Comment: @ChanjungKim - What if the row went first into a "pending" table.  Then if/when it was properly handled, it is moved to the 'real' table. ??

Comment: @RickJames, We can implement this kind of thing in many ways. I just want to know whether MySQL has the exact feature or not. And I guess the answer is no.

Comment: The answer is "No; MySQL does not have such a feature."  Do you want a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for same you can create an event by this way 

`CREATE EVENT lifetime ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '14:05:44' ENDS '14:05:46'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    DO BEGIN
    // put your delete query here with where clause by calculate your exp date
     END`

Comment: No, This is not the one I am asking. It is just creating an event. I don't want to create any events but giving an option to a row when I create a table like `auto_increment`.